# Как считать строки в документе с конкретным словом + вывести к ним дату из строки?

Tags: bash

У меня есть файл с примерно таким содержанием

```
2011-10-12 14:22:44 OK
2011-10-12 16:11:41 OK
2012-02-11 14:12:31 OK
2015-05-05 03:17:11 
2015-08-06 12:11:31 
2020-07-07 11:17:51 OK
2020-05-08 14:15:21
```

Мне нужно взять и посчитать количество строк с выводом "ОК" (их всего 4) в конкретный день.
То есть вывод должен быть примерно таким:

```
2011-10-12 2
2012-02-11 1
2015-05-05 0
2015-08-06 0
2020-07-07 1
2020-05-08 0
```

Как грепать и считать сколько всего строк с OK, я понимаю, а вот как еще и дату к этому вывести,не понимаю.

Вот что у меня есть

```
for i  in `cat $1 | grep "OK" | wc -l`
do     
echo $i 
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это довольно простой скрипт на *Awk*:

```awk
{
    if ($3 == "OK") {
        a[$1]++;
    } else {
        a[$1] = 0;
    }
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        print i " " a[i];
    }
}
```

```sh
awk -f ./tmp.awk ./tmp.txt
```

```
2020-05-08 0
2015-08-06 0
2020-07-07 1
2012-02-11 1
2011-10-12 2
2015-05-05 0
```

Можно даже однострочником:

```sh
$ awk '{$3=="OK"?a[$1]++:a[$1]=0}END{for(i in a)print(i,a[i])}' ./tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще для таких целей существуют популярные специализированные системы для визуализации логов. Вроде, Kibana так должна уметь. Стоит это помнить, когда самописные скрипты будут усложняться.

Предложу в качестве идеи совершенно примитивное и быстрое решение.

Решение основано на [ответе с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017281/reading-a-csv-file-with-sql-querys-from-linux-shell), где используется [такая утилита q от пользователя harelba на github.com](https://github.com/harelba/q), которая позволяет делать SQL-запросы к CSV файлу.

```
$ cat example.log | q -d ' ' "SELECT c1, COUNT(CASE WHEN c3='OK' THEN 1 END) FROM - GROUP BY 1"
2011-10-12 2
2012-02-11 1
2015-05-05 0
2015-08-06 0
2020-05-08 0
2020-07-07 1
```

Я сохранил приведенный пример данных в файл `example.log` и получилось его интерпретировать как CSV-файл с тремя колонками (c1...c3), где разделителем выступает пробел (`-d ' '`).